# Set timeout expiration in ms sql 7

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to perform a query in a transactional database that was used for more than 3 years. But it always says timeout expired after running for about 30 seconds when I try to run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tblBPLedgerBill LEFT JOIN
    tblAssessment ON 
    tblBPLedgerBill.strAssessmentID = tblAssessment.ObjID
WHERE tblAssessment.intType = 0 AND curSurcharge != 0
```

Is it possible to adjust how many seconds the query should take before it terminates it.

Comment: How are you running it? Query analyzer, osql, ssms, sqlcmd, access, etc?

Comment: from the sql server enterprise manager

Answer (score 1):

Check the connection properties.
Click Option button when connecting to the Management Studio (EM).